# React Native DateTimePicker styling issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datetime, datepicker, react-datepicker

I am having styling issues React Native DateTimePicker '@hashiprobr/react-native-paper-datetimepicker';
https://github.com/hashiprobr/react-native-paper-datetimepicker#peer-dependencies

My date picker need to be like first picture.

[image: This is my desing]

But I got this

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  import { DateTimePicker } from '@hashiprobr/react-native-paper-datetimepicker';

    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [value, setValue] = useState(false);


        <View style={styles.pickerContainer}>
        <View style={styles.firstPicker}>
          <Text style={styles.pickerText}>Event Start</Text>
          <DateTimePicker style={styles.picker} type="date" value={date} onChangeDate={setDate} underlineColor={Colors.Transparent} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.pickerText}>Event End</Text>
          <DateTimePicker style={styles.picker} type="date" value={date} onChangeDate={setDate} underlineColor={Colors.Transparent} />
        </View>
      </View>

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     firstPicker: {
     marginRight: 15,
     },
      picker: {
      borderColor: Colors.PurpleLight,
      borderRadius: 1,
      borderWidth: 1,
     },
    pickerContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginVertical: 20,
     },
    pickerText: {
    color: Colors.GrayLight,
    textAlign: 'left',
     },
   });
```